# Are all brute force algorithms exponential?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

Every example I have seen of brute force algorithm has exponential run time.

Is this a strict rule, i.e. are *all* brute force algorithms exponential in run time?

Answer (score 11):

No, certainly not. Consider a linear search algorithm to search a sorted array. You can do better,  but a linear search could be considered "brute force".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search for further examples and explanation. A relevant quote from that page:

> While a brute-force search is simple to implement, and will always find a solution if it exists, its cost is proportional to the number of candidate solutions - which in many practical problems tends to grow very quickly as the size of the problem increases.

Comment: Greg, Thank you. Catalin Pol made a comment about "exponential" often being synonymous to "non-polynomial" in CS. So, would it still be false to say that all brute force algorithms are non-polynomial? I am guessing so because you gave an example of a linear brute force algorithm. But I just want to confirm...

Comment: @StellaJ: Yes, my linear search counterexample shows that the general "all brute force algorithms are non-polynomial" is false.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You can also do worse.

Example, finding the shortest tour (travelling salesman) using brute force is Omega(n!), which is not exponential.

Comment: Actually, the term "exponential" is used often in CS as a synonym for "non-polynomial". So, even if indeed O(n!) is worse than any O(n^k), you may still find it in CS books as an 'exponential' algorithm

Comment: So then, would it be true to say that all brute force algorithms are non-polynomial? I am guessing not due to Greg's answer. But do you agree? Thanks!

Comment: @Catalin Pol said "In CS exponential is synonymous with non-polynomial". Sorry, that is completely wrong. There are sub-exponential algorithms which are non-polynomial (for example, unique games!). No Computer scientist worth their salt would interchange the two. Stella: Greg's answer is fine. Catalin is wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sub-exponential algorithm that cannot be upperbounded by a polynomial function? I always thought that P stands for 'polynomial' and NP is for 'non-polynomial'... not much room for a third option

Comment: @Caitlin: NP stands for non-deterministic polynomial. I suggest you look up the definitions. This is a common mistake made by beginning students. For a sub-exponential non-polynomial, I already mentioned unique games, but for a simpler example, consider an algorithm which runs in n^(log n) time. This is neither bounded above by a polynomial, nor is it exponential.